# Require libpcre.so.0 when install ganglia with yum on RHEL7.3

Tags: rhel7, ganglia

When I try to install ganglia on RHEL7.3 using yum, it says requires libpcre.so.0()(64bit)[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH9kt.png). I have libpcre.so.1 in the /usr/lib64 file, and I install the old version pcre manually, and put libpcre.so.0 into /usr/lib, /usr/lib64, /usr/local/lib, as shown in images [libpcre.so.* found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mybLX.png), the problem still not solved, does anyone know how to solve this problem? Appriciate your help!

Comment: Please copy and paste the text from your images into your question.

Comment: Tried to reinstall libpcre, but deleted libpcre.so.1 and system was down. Only these two images left for the problem.